# Entity Framework not generating INNER JOIN with .Include

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a project where an `.Include` does not generate an INNER JOIN, while the INNER JOIN is generated in other projects using the same DbContext and code.

I am using EF Core Code-First. The DbContext is shared with other projects through NuGet.

Below are the two classes in question and their configuration in the DbContext:

```
[Table("Project", Schema = "ProjectManagement")]
public class AxosoftProject
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int AxosoftId { get; set; }
    public int? AxosoftParentId { get; set; }

    public AxosoftProject AxosoftParent { get; set; }
    public List<AxosoftProject> Children { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AxosoftItem> Items { get; set; }
}

[Table("Item", Schema = "ProjectManagement")]
public class AxosoftItem
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int AxosoftId { get; set; }
    public int AxosoftProjectId { get; set; }
    public AxosoftProject AxosoftProject { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public string SubItemType { get; set; }
    public decimal PercentComplete { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AxosoftProject>().HasKey(x => x.AxosoftId);
modelBuilder.Entity<AxosoftProject>().HasOne(x => x.AxosoftParent).WithMany(x => x.Children);
modelBuilder.Entity<AxosoftProject>().HasMany(x => x.Items);

modelBuilder.Entity<AxosoftItem>().HasKey(x => x.AxosoftId);
modelBuilder.Entity<AxosoftItem>().HasOne(x => x.AxosoftProject);
```

Code to query all projects and their items:

```
IMyEntities MyEntities = new MyEntities("Server=localhost;Database=MyEntities;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

var projects = MyEntities.AxosoftProjects.Include(x => x.Items).ToList();

var listwithitems = projects.Where(x => x.Items != null).ToList();
```

Depending on the project that I execute above code in, it will either do an INNER JOIN or no INNER JOIN at all. I tried deleting the whole project where above code does not perform an INNER JOIN, cloning it from the repository afterwards to start from fresh, still no INNER JOIN.

How do I go about debugging this further? I suspect the project where it doesn't work may be using an old version of the DLL's even if it looks like it's pointing to the correct ones.

**UPDATE**

To verify that the include is indeed not working, I did an additional test. If I load the AxosoftItems into the DbContext seperately, then EF will populate the Items collections for each AxosoftProject. Example:

```
var projects = MyEntities.AxosoftProjects.Include(x => x.Items).ToList();

var listwithitems1 = projects.Where(x => x.Items != null).ToList(); // 0 items

var items = MyEntities.AxosoftItems.ToList();

var listwithitems2 = projects.Where(x => x.Items != null).ToList(); // 41 items
```

**UPDATE 2**

The code and reference to EF Core was placed in an ASP.NET MVC project. Moving the code to a separate class library "fixes" the issue, the INNER JOIN is not ignored, and the code is exactly the same. I intend to download the source code and debug my way through, to figure out why the Include is being ignored in the MVC project.

Comment: _"it will either do an INNER JOIN or no INNER JOIN at all"_ - how did you determine this? Through the SQL Server Profiler? Or based on the data you see? If the former, make sure you reference the same NuGet version. Perhaps you've installed an earlier version where the relation hasn't been configured. Check the DLL version, or if you don't do proper versioning, decompile the DLL (for example using JustDecompile). If the DLL versions _are_ exactly the same but you're using a different database, inspect your data. We really can't answer this.

Comment: I determined it through the SQL Server Profiler. Also tried decompiling the DLL's with JetBrains decompiler (pushing F12 on the classes) and comparing them. What I find weird is that when I create a new project and decompile, the assembly location is in a different project than the one I am looking at in VS. So decompiling from project A will show an assembly location from project B.

Comment: I will try to Publish the project to a folder and compare the DLL's, maybe that will show something

Comment: @CodeCaster the dll's seem to be the correct version, when publishing the project to a seperate folder. Also used the Modules window to find the correct path to the dll's used by IIS, they are also the correct version. Check my updated question, did some additional debugging. EF seems to populate the Items collection if I manually select the items from the DB, this must means that the plumbworking with relations in the DbContext is good.